# NodeJS Sequelize error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Model define

```
// Stock
export default function(app: Application) {
  const { STRING, BIGINT, TIME, TINYINT } = app.Sequelize;

  const Stock = app.model.define('stock', {
    id: {
      type: BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    uid: {
      type: BIGINT,
    },
    aid: {
      type: BIGINT,
    },
    symbol: {
      type: STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: STRING,
      comment: 'name',
    },
    ....
  });

  return class extends Stock {};
}
// TransactionRecord
export default function(app: Application) {
  const { STRING, BIGINT, TIME, TINYINT, INTEGER, DECIMAL } = app.Sequelize;

  const TransactionRecord = app.model.define('transaction_record', {
    id: {
      type: BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    uid: {
      type: BIGINT,
    },
    aid: {
      type: BIGINT,
    },
    sid: {
      type: BIGINT,
    },
    ...
  });
  return class extends TransactionRecord {
    static associate() {
      app.model.TransactionRecord.belongsTo(app.model.Account, {
        as: 'account',
        foreignKey: 'aid',
      });
      app.model.TransactionRecord.belongsTo(app.model.User, {
        as: 'user',
        foreignKey: 'uid',
      });
      app.model.TransactionRecord.belongsTo(app.model.Stock, {
        as: 'stock',
        foreignKey: 'sid',
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Now I am getting the follwing error, Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous. how can i uniquely grab the correct ID from this statment

Error Desc:

> code: 'ER_NON_UNIQ_ERROR',
> errno: 1052,
> sqlState: '23000',
> sqlMessage: "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous",
> sql: 'SELECT count(DISTINCT(`` .`id`)) AS `count` FROM `transaction_record` AS ``  LEFT OUTER JOIN `stock` AS `stock` ON
> `` .`id` = `stock`.`sid` LEFT OUTER JOIN `account` AS `account` ON `` .`id` = `account`.`aid` WHERE ``.`uid` = 1;',
> parameters: undefined   },

```
      const offset = Math.max(Number(pageNo || 1) - 1, 0);
      const limit = Number(pageSize || 20);
      const result = await ctx.model.TransactionRecord.findAndCountAll({
        raw: true,
        distinct: true,
        offset: offset * limit,
        limit,
        where: {
          uid: Number(ctx.payload.id),
        },
        order: [
          [ 'updated', 'ASC' ],
        ],
        include: [
          {
            model: app.model.Stock,
            as: 'stock',
            attributes: [ 'symbol', 'name', 'market', 'currency' ],
          },
          {
            model: app.model.Account,
            as: 'account',
            attributes: [ 'name', 'super', 'currency' ],
          },
        ],
      });
```

Please help me, thx

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same field in both the tables then because of that this error is coming.

For this, you have to give the name of the field along with the name of the table, so that it can be known which table this field belongs to.